# Slack company members not visible to all

Tags: slack, slack-api

1. Is it possible for a Company to set up a Slack account which prevents members from being visible to other members?
2. Only the company can add, remove and see all members
3. And grant access to members to interact with each other on a one-on-one basis only.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. You can put a lot of restrictions on a Slack workspace, but there are some basic collaboration functionality you can not restrict:

1. No, Users will always be able to see who else is on the Slack, e.g. by tying @name in any channel. Also users in a private channel will be able to invite others into that channel.
2. Partly, you can restrict it, so that only users will admin role can invite and kick users. But existing users will be visible to all (see #1).
3. No, Users are always able to sent direct message to other uses. This can not be restricted.